# How can I move my conda environments from /home to another location?

Tags: python, conda

My conda envs default to installing in my home directory (linux), but they are getting huge and /home isn't meant for that.  How can I (a) move my envs to another network location, and (b) change the default where new envs will be made?

The new location and home are both visible at the same time, so that is not a concern.

Comment: You likely want to move both the package cache and the environment location (as per duplicate), otherwise Conda can't save space with hardlinking. To actually move the environments you should recreate them after transferring the package cache.

Comment: _move my envs to another network location_ What, exactly, do you mean by "network location"?  Move to a different computer?  Or just to a different local filesystem directory?

Comment: I'm on linux, so there are network drives e.g. /data/bigdisk/ or something.  Nothing is local to my computer where I work, not /home or anything.  Well, you can access local storage but it is not backed up so it's just for temporary storage.